# How do I check to see if a list index exists in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I have the following snippet of code:

```
public static List<string> sqlData = new List<string>();

//
//  lots of code here
//

if (/* check here to see if the sqlData[whatever] index exists  */)
{
    sqlData.Insert(count2, sqlformatted);
}
else
{
    sqlData.Insert(count2, sqlformatted + sqlData[count2]);
}
```

What I want to know is how to check the index on sqlData to see if it exists before trying to insert something that contains itself.

Comment: I think your question is badly worded, and the variety of different answers you are getting shows that people are interpreting it differently. Please clarify what you want, perhaps with an example.

Comment: if possible, stick to foreach(var sqlString in sqlData)

Comment: Let me post the entire section of code.

Comment: I updated the code above to give you a bigger picture.

Comment: @Mark:  I'm not the best as formulating questions about C# because I'm very new to the language.  I recently came off the PHP bandwagon to join this one =P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If whatever is always positive then you can use this:

```
if (whatever < sqlData.Count) { ... }
```

Or if whatever could also be negative then you need to add a test for that too:

```
if (whatever >= 0 && whatever < sqlData.Count) { ... }
```

Comment: When I go to use sqlData.Length, it Visual C# Express 2010 doesn't offer it as an option.

Comment: @Claude: Sorry that was an error. It's Count for lists (Length for arrays). I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Abe Miessler: I think it should be OK. If the list is length 1, then 0 is the largest valid index.

Comment: @Abe: Either `< sqlData.Count` or `<= sqlData.Count - 1` should be ok.

Answer (score 4):

Check the length against the index:

```
sqlData.Count < count2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(sqlData.Count > whatever )
{
 //index "whatever" exists
  string str = sqlData[whatever];

}
```